# How to install Python Virtualenv?

Tags: python, installation, virtualenv

I'm new to Python. I need to install "Virtualenv" but I don't can't figure out how it works and how to install it.

I have downloaded and uncompress virtualenv-1.5.2. What sould be my next step?

Best Regards,

Comment: Your next step should have been your first step: Read [the manual](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). If you have done this, please be more concrete in your question. What part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the uncompressed virtualenv directory run

> python setup.py install

You should also learn about easy_install and pip for Python package installation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have installed in this way: "python C:\virtualenv-1.5.2\virtualenv.py --distribute python_virtualenv". This will create a directory with the virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Just install [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads), it already includes virtualenv, easy_install, pip and PyPM.